# XML - get sub node value

Tags: xml

I'm new to parsing XML. I dug into this but can't find the answer. How do I directly get a sub-node value?

```
<root>
  <fedex>
    <code>fed1</code>
  </fedex>
  <uspx>
    <code>**uspx1**</code>
  </uspx>
</root>
```

How do I get the code value within the USPX element directly?

This "works" but I don't think it's the correct way:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("shipper.xml");
string uspxCode = xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("code")).Skip(1).First().Value;
```

Conceptually, I would like to drill directly such as "get value from "/uspx/code" instead of get 2nd code value from list of code values.

Comment: XPath is one good way to do this. What language are you using?

Comment: c# ... with Xpath, once I change it to XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); ... etc ... then how do I access the specific code value within the USPX element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here's one way to do it ...

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("shipper.xml");

XmlNode uspx = doc.SelectSingleNode("/bookstore/uspx/code");
Label.Text = uspx.FirstChild.Value;
```

thanks!