# Simplest way to get a single value out of an XML string?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to get a single value out of a big XML string. I've got a string holding something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<UserInfo>
    <User>
        <First>Alice</First>
        <Last>Avery</Last>
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Age>25</Age>
        <OtherThing>
            <with>stuff</with>
            <in>it</in>
        </OtherThing>
    </User>
</UserInfo>
```

Only much bigger and uglier, and all I want to get is the ID value: "12345". ID may have attributes on it and they may vary, or I'd probably just search the string with a regex. It seems like you ought to be able to do something like this in only 2 or 3 lines.

Comment: linq-to-xml should provide a simple, straightforward solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML - get sub node value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290214/xml-get-sub-node-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I think is using: [XmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) method.

So like in provided example of MSDN itself, you can do:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");

    doc["item"]["name"].InnerText; //WILL RETURN "wrench"
```

The only thing I would invite your attention on this that XmlDocument is loaded entirely in memory and based on the size of that string that *can* become non efficient. 
So this depends on the actual size of data you operating on.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: proided link, as usual for MSDN docs, constains also an example that suggests how to proceed.  By the way edited answer too.

Comment: The example in your link does not demonstrate how to match an element, but your answer now does, so everything's fine. (By the way, why apply `ToString()` to `InnerText`, which is already a string?)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: typo...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
int id = (int)doc.XPathSelectElement("UserInfo/User/ID");
```

Comment: +1, didn't know about that cast possibility, I've always used `Convert` on the value.

Answer (score 1):

If the `ID` value is going to occur only once in the xml, it might be faster to simply run it through a regex.

```
<ID.*?>(.*?)</ID>
```

If you need to run through the document tree then you may need to parse the xml, and use XPath or something to get the value.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNode idNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//UserInfo/User/ID");
Console.WriteLine(idNode.InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which takes an XPath expression as parameter. Here's a [starter](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) tutorial on XPath, it is a language on it's own and can be pretty powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider linq-to-xml.

The following provides an example:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(“<…/>”);
var id = document.XPathSelectElement("/UserInfo/User/ID").Value;
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to XML.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(XMLstring);
IEnumerable<string> values = from elem in doc.Descendants("User") select elem.Element("ID").Value;
```

Please see [LINQ to XML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This should work also:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        XDocument file = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
        var query = file.Element("UserInfo").Element("User").Element("ID").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(query);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```